# Ajuda com cláusula ORDER BY por string

Tags: mysql, query, select

Tenho o seguinte comando select:

```
select nome, case grau when 0 then 'QS' when 1 then 'CI' when 2 then 'CDC' when 3 then 'QM' end grau, case faixa when 0 then 'NÃO' when 1 then 'SIM' end faixa, mensalidade from socio order by grau, nome
```

Ele está ordenando alfabeticamente pelo campo GRAU, porém eu quero que ele ordene na seguinte sequencia:

QM, CDC, CI, QS

Como eu faço essa alteração?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
select nome
    , grau as grau_ordem
    , case grau 
        when 0 then 'QS' 
        when 1 then 'CI' 
        when 2 then 'CDC' 
        when 3 then 'QM' 
        end grau
    , case faixa 
        when 0 then 'NÃO' 
        when 1 then 'SIM' 
        end faixa
    , mensalidade 
from socio 
order by grau_ordem desc
    , nome
```

Assim, você ordena pelo valor desejado (o prórpio numérico) e tem a coluna de exibição.